# MariaDB Multi level replication (replicate from replica)

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

I am looking for a way to set up MariaDB replication from a replica.
My configuration looks as following:

First datacenter:
Primary + 3 replicas connected via private switch

Second datacenter:
Primary + 3 replicas connected via private switch

Primary from second datacenter should replicate from primary from first dataceter via public network (this is working)
And replicas from second dataceter should replicate from primary from second datacenter via private network.

The problem is that configuring Primary from second datacenter to replicate from first Primary, then it is not creating own binlog (binlog is on "log-bin", binlog file is created but empty all time) so Replicas cannot replicate from it. Is there any way to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these are needed:

```
log_bin
log_slave_updates
```

Be aware that if the Primary in the second DC goes down, the Replicas in the same DC will not be receiving updates.  A partial workaround is to have some of the Replicas in DC-2 replicate directly from the Primary in DC-1.

Comment: log_slave_updates, exactly what i was looking for! thank you!

Comment: @forke - Yeah, LOTS of people get tripped up by it.